# Declaring variables in numba jitclass

Tags: python, numba

I'm getting a KeyError on the dictionary when I try to import the following jitclass:

```
from numba import jitclass, float64

spec = [('n', float64),
        ('w', float64),
        ('a', float64)]

@jitclass(spec)
class foo:

    def __init__(self,n,w):

        self.n = n
        self.w = w

    def foo2(self):

        a = self.n*self.w

        return a + 1.
```

I do not understand where the error is coming from. The numba documentation is inadequate for explaining things. Do I need all variables to be class variables?

Comment: Your class doesn't have an `a` field. Why do you list one in the spec?

Comment: I get the same error if I pull the 'a' entry out of spec, so that doesn't actually seem to be the problem. Or it is in a really obtuse way.

Answer (score 1):

The `jitclass` needs to inherit from `object`:

```
from numba import jitclass, float64

spec = [('n', float64),
        ('w', float64),
        ('a', float64)]

@jitclass(spec)
class foo(object):

    def __init__(self,n,w):

        self.n = n
        self.w = w

    def foo2(self):

        a = self.n*self.w

        return a + 1.
```

This doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation as a requirement, but it's how the examples are written.

Comment: Thank you! That would be a really important thing to mention in the documentation.